# webRequest/declarativeNetRequest - Match data: URI

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to block requests from local files starting with `data:` using a Chrome Extension. However I haven't been able to do so using the URL match and filter options available for `webRequest` and `declarativeNetRequest`.

I found this [chromium bug](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/919984) which appears as merged but I haven't found a way to block `data:` requests successfully.

Below is an example of the request I'm trying to block:

[image]

When using the feature `Enable network request blocking` in Chrome the `data:` request gets successfully blocked. I want to achieve the same effect with a Chrome Extension. (See blocked `data:` request below)

[image]

Is there any way or creative work-around to effectively block `data:` requests using a Chrome Extension the same way the native feature `Enable network request blocking` in Chrome can do?

Comment: `data:` URLs don't produce network requests so these API can't block them.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm I have edited the question to clarify the requests I'm trying to block. Using the feature `Enable network request blocking` in Chrome I can indeed block `data:` requests (see screenshots in the question above). I would like to achieve the same using a Chrome extension

Comment: Devtools is using a special CDP command [Network.setBlockedURLs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setBlockedURLs) which is processed differently. You can do the same in an extension by using chrome.debugger API but it'll show a warning above all pages.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @wOxxOm. It would have been nice to have it available without `chrome.debugger`. Perhaps a feature request for future releases or future manifests